# How do I tell if LEGO bricks are fake?

Tags: minifigures

I recently bought a large lot of LEGO bricks, come to find out that more than half are fake. There are some minifigures that are real and some are obvious fakes, but the Minecraft ones I can’t tell. Do all Minecraft minifigure parts have “LEGO” logo on them like other LEGO elements, or did I get scammed?

Comment: on top of their torsos, on the neck there should be lego mark on top. can you check? and under legs too.

Comment: Hi CliffGang! Please check the answers provided on the page linked as the duplicate. If those do not answer your question to your satisfaction, please edit your original post to incorporate additional details, or add a comment here to let us know you are still looking for an answer.